# Convert summed daily sales array into string in php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am struggling to make this PHP array convert to the string format I require.

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$result1 = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

  $result1[strtotime($row['DOB'])][strtotime($row['DOB'])] = strtotime($row['DOB']);

  $result1[strtotime($row['DOB'])]['PRICE'] += $row['PRICE'];



}
print_r($result1);
```

Current output is:

```
[1136246400] => Array
    (
        [1136246400] => 1136246400
        [PRICE] => 165.5
    )

 [1136332800] => Array
    (
        [1136332800] => 1136332800
        [PRICE] => 169.5
    )
```

And I need it to be:

```
   Array ( [0] => [1136246400, 165.5] [1] => [1136332800, 169.5] )
```

Quite new to PHP - any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you need something like below:

```
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $result1[$i][0] = strtotime($row['DOB']);
  // to avoid warning in $result1[$i][1] += $row['PRICE']; 
  if(!isset($result1[$i][1]))
     $result1[$i][1] = 0;
  // -----------
  $result1[$i][1] += $row['PRICE'];
  $i++;
}
print_r($result1);
```

Comment: Thanks for this.

However, the original code sums the PRICE for date values that match each other (I have multiple individual PRICE values per date). How would I now sum PRICE by each date?